# How to parameterize xpath and parse it as a text?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, automated-tests, parameterized-unit-test

I have a python file, Base.Py

```
def provideElectricJobDetails(self):
        self.ui.driver.find_element_by_name("Title").send_keys("Test")
        self.ui.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Select AOR...')]").click()
        self.ui.sleep(2)
        self.ui.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Cheyenne')]").click()
        self.ui.sleep(2)
        self.ui.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Submit')]").click()
```

And another python file, CreateNew.Py

```
def testCreateNewOtherJob(self):
        self.ui.common.clickNavbarNewJob()
        self.ui.jobs.selectServiceType('Electric')
        self.ui.jobs.selectJobType('Other')
        self.ui.jobs.ProvideElectricJobDetails()
```

My question is, Instead of hardcoding in the Base.Py as `("//span[contains(text(),'Submit')]")`.
How can I parse it as text format, so that I could call in the CreateNew.Py as

```
self.ui.jobs.selectButton("Submit")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I right understood, you want something like this:

```
def selectButton(name):
    self.ui.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'" + name + "')]").click()


def testCreateNewOtherJob(self):
    self.ui.jobs.selectButton("Submit") # will click on 'Submit' button
    self.ui.jobs.selectButton("Select AOR...") # will click on 'Select AOR...' button
```

Comment: This was exactly what  I needed. Thanks.